# Would moving the search field help?

Tags: feature-request, search, user-interface

I came here after hearing the StackExchange podcast and the first thing I said to myself was, "Is there not a search option?" It seems I either scrolled or ignored the very top header and instead looked to the Questions, Tags, Users, etc. buttons.

Maybe it is a nit pick but sites like engadget and slashdot both have similarly styled headers and I ignore them because they are usually just advertising for their respective parent companies and other associated sites. It seems more reasonable to make either the search field itself or a button that says Search and include it with the other, more prominent, buttons that appear next to the site logos than to relegate it to the same place where the 'about' option is(since one would assume that the about option is useful only once or twice and search is relevant often). To restate the question, if stackoverflow and the StackExchange are meant as repositories for the consolidation of knowledge, shouldn't the consumption(search) of that knowledge be promoted as heavily as the creation(Questions and Unanswered)?

Comment: you might want to rethink your checkmark

Answer (score 6):

The standard convention is for the search box to be at the top right of the page.

[image]

Comment: [Indeed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5V3Zs.png) ;-)

Comment: Whose convention? None of those are above the logo and the amazon image shows centered more than on the right. check out yahoo, google, facebook, slashdot, and twitter. they all do not have search fields above the main logo or all the way to the right